# Spring Reactive Security API Gateway with OpenID Connect, using private_key_jwt (login.gov)

Tags: spring-security, jwt, key, private, reactive

I'm following along with this 2-part tutorial.

- [Part 1](https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/10/spring-security-5-2-oauth-2-exploration-part1/)
- [Part 2](https://blog.jdriven.com/2019/10/spring-security-5-2-oauth-2-exploration-part2/)

**The goal described**:

> The API Gateway will serve as example of performing an OAuth 2
>   Authorization code flow based Login with session management.
>   Furthermore it will display how to augment HTTP requests with the
>   proper OAuth bearer token as required by the resource server. Key
>   take-away being that the access/refresh token as acquired from
>   Keycloak will never be exposed to the browser.

The difference is that I'm not leveraging Keycloak, I am using Login.gov, and -- from my experience -- integrating with them can be quite painful, despite their decent [documentation](https://developers.login.gov/oidc/)

**The problem**:

The tutorial thinks I can get away with something as basic as:

```
...
    .oauth2Login()
```

Previously, when I was NOT using a gateway paradigm or reactive programming model, I had done a lot of tweaking of oauth on my security config to integrate with Login.gov, such as:

```
...
    .oauth2Login()
        .loginPage(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.DEFAULT_LOGIN_PAGE_URL)
        .authorizationEndpoint()
        .authorizationRequestResolver(new LoginGovAuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository))
        .authorizationRequestRepository(authorizationRequestRepository())
        .and()
        .tokenEndpoint()
        .accessTokenResponseClient(accessTokenResponseClient())
        .and()
        .failureHandler(new LoginGovAuthenticationFailureHandler())
        .successHandler(new LoginGovAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
```

There's obviously a lot going on here, but the point is: all those jumping through hoops was mostly to do a couple things (that I can remember):

- add 2 params in the request resolver

  - `acr_values` (constant: could be added in config `authorization_uri`)
  - `nonce` (22-character min, and at least then required a resolver)

```
additionalParameters.put("acr_values", LoginGovConstants.LOGIN_GOV_LOA1)
additionalParameters.put("nonce", nonce)
```

Furthermore, the converter apparently necessitated me signing my own JWT and providing it `client_assertion` and the constant `client_assertion_type` parameters:

```
    @Override
    RequestEntity<?> convert(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest authorizationCodeGrantRequest) {
        RequestEntity<?> originalRequestEntity = super.convert(authorizationCodeGrantRequest)
        String registrationId = resolveRegistrationId(authorizationCodeGrantRequest)
        if(registrationId == LoginGovConstants.LOGIN_GOV_REGISTRATION_ID) {
            ClientRegistration clientRegistration = clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId(registrationId)
            String clientId = clientRegistration.clientId
            String clientSecret = clientRegistration.clientSecret
            String tokenUri = clientRegistration.providerDetails.tokenUri
            Long expirationTime = LoginGovConstants.LOGIN_GOV_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME

            String jwt = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(clientId)
                .withIssuer(clientId)
                .withAudience(tokenUri)
                // Should be an un-guessable, random string generated by the client
                .withJWTId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expirationTime))
                .sign(Algorithm.RSA256(keystoreUtil.rsaPublicKey(), keystoreUtil.rsaPrivateKey()))

            HttpHeaders headers = originalRequestEntity.headers
            MultiValueMap<String, String> formParameters = originalRequestEntity.body as MultiValueMap<String, String>
            URI uri = originalRequestEntity.url

            formParameters.add("client_assertion", jwt)
            formParameters.add("client_assertion_type", LoginGovConstants.LOGIN_GOV_CLIENT_ASSERTION_TYPE)
            return new RequestEntity<?>(formParameters, headers, HttpMethod.POST, uri)
        }
    }
```

Suffice to say, at the time I implemented my previous solution, it seemed like a lot of backflips to accomplish some extra URL parameters that I thought Spring Security should provide by default. So if we can improve on my previous appraoch, I would appreciate some guidance.

Nevertheless, with this new API gateway approach, I'm further confused, considering Webflux and a reactive paradigm.

For example:

- `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequestEntityConverter` vs. `ServerOAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationTokenConverter`
- `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` vs. `ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver`

What is the overlap between these classes, if any?

Is there an easier way to accomplish what I had previously done with these different `Server*` classes?

**Current behavior**:

Following the tutorial I mentioned, I have a partial flow going with my gateway, but the picture is not complete:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          login-gov:
            client-id: \${LOGIN_GOV_CLIENT_ID}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope:
              - openid
              - email
        provider:
          login-gov:
            authorization-uri: https://idp.int.identitysandbox.gov/openid_connect/authorize
            token-uri: https://idp.int.identitysandbox.gov/api/openid_connect/token?client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
            user-info-uri: https://idp.int.identitysandbox.gov/api/openid_connect/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: https://idp.int.identitysandbox.gov/api/openid_connect/certs
            user-name-attribute: sub
```

Login.gov is using the `private_key_jwt` authentication method, and that seems to mean I have no "client-secret". Is this why it was necessary for me to create and sign my own JWT in my previous implementation?

This is the output of the gateway when I've hit a gateway endpoint (/api/user/api/v1/savesearches/) that should eventually redirect to an actual service.

The login flow initiates as expected, and I enter my credentials on the integration Login.gov page. Once I submit, I am ultimately redirected back to an error page `/login?error`

```
2020-04-20 14:10:30.934 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-10] HTTP GET "/api/user/api/v1/savesearches/"
2020-04-20 14:10:30.983 DEBUG 15352 --- [oundedElastic-2] o.s.w.s.s.DefaultWebSessionManager       : Created new WebSession.
2020-04-20 14:10:30.995 DEBUG 15352 --- [oundedElastic-2] .s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2020-04-20 14:10:30.996 DEBUG 15352 --- [oundedElastic-2] .s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : Processing text/html
2020-04-20 14:10:30.996 DEBUG 15352 --- [oundedElastic-2] .s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : text/html .isCompatibleWith text/html = true
2020-04-20 14:10:30.997 DEBUG 15352 --- [oundedElastic-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-10] Completed 302 FOUND
2020-04-20 14:10:31.006 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-11] HTTP GET "/oauth2/authorization/login-gov"
2020-04-20 14:10:31.017 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-11] Completed 302 FOUND
2020-04-20 14:10:31.853 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-12] HTTP GET "/api/user/api/v1/savesearches/"
2020-04-20 14:10:31.861 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] .s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2020-04-20 14:10:31.861 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] .s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : Processing text/html
2020-04-20 14:10:31.861 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] .s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : text/html .isCompatibleWith text/html = true
2020-04-20 14:10:31.861 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-12] Completed 302 FOUND
2020-04-20 14:10:31.868 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-13] HTTP GET "/oauth2/authorization/login-gov"
2020-04-20 14:10:31.874 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-13] Completed 302 FOUND
2020-04-20 14:10:44.361 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-14] HTTP GET "/login/oauth2/code/login-gov?code=d2236ca8-1458-4631-b067-057f461d2a71&state=pp0V-IpV75MSgq995i5IUoQvuaFGhBXBJyRiHsAhQvM%3D"
2020-04-20 14:10:44.382 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [312e7ca5] HTTP POST https://idp.int.identitysandbox.gov/api/openid_connect/token?client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
2020-04-20 14:10:44.950 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : [312e7ca5] Writing form fields [grant_type, code, redirect_uri, client_id, code_verifier] (content masked)
2020-04-20 14:10:45.080 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [312e7ca5] Response 400 BAD_REQUEST
2020-04-20 14:10:45.094 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : [312e7ca5] Decoded [{error=Client assertion Nil JSON web token}]
2020-04-20 14:10:45.095 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-14] Completed 302 FOUND
2020-04-20 14:10:45.099 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-15] HTTP GET "/login?error"
2020-04-20 14:10:45.101 DEBUG 15352 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [eae7892d-15] Completed 200 OK
```

What stands out to me is very clear here. I can see the authorization step succeed, as indicated by the redirect to `/login/oauth2/code/login-gov?code=d2236ca8-1458-4631-b067-057f461d2a71&state=pp0V-IpV75MSgq995i5IUoQvuaFGhBXBJyRiHsAhQvM%3D` with the `code` and `state` parameters existing.

What is confusing are the parameters provided to the the token endpoint: it only has the `client_assertion_type` that I provided in the config above, but it should have the actual `client_assertion` (JWT) too. I presume, this is all the hoop-jumping I had done before to create a JWT in the custom converter, but I never understood why Spring didn't do this for me?

Am I missing some basic configuration step? If not, I could use some help to re-implement the converter in a reactive (ServerWebExchange) kind of way.

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

FYI [Spring Security 5 does not yet support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6881) `private_key_jwt` which is why you're having to do extra work to get it working.

(Adding an answer as I don't have enough reputation to comment)

Comment: I think in the meantime, they added the support: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-idtoken-verify and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/9520. But with this information I still have no clue how to get it work.